# Connect to amazon web serives using jupyter notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a deep learning model and would like to use Jupyter notebooks, the problem is that the model is too large to train in my computer and will need to use AWS EC2 instances. I already have the instance and everything configured but the problem is that I don't have a graphical interface in EC2 to edit my Jupyter notebook

How can I use Jupyter notebook from my personal computer but have all the computational power in a EC2 intance? Hope I have made myself clear, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a detailed tutorial on how to do that:

https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/blob/master/AWS-EC2-Instance-Setup/EC2_Setup.pdf

You will also need to set up your Jupyter config file:

```
c = get_config()

# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'

# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile = '/home/ec2-user/certs/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  
c.NotebookApp.password = 'sha1:1234506898:20033bbca0ccf25117653............'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```